# Why does my push-notification only work just when I have Alert();

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, push-notification

I want to have a notification when an SMS is delivered to my SMS-panel. This code gets a new SMS from JSON file and every 5 sec, I want to check whether I have a new message or not if yes then show a notification.

I get the sms and save it as json in a file.
The notification is in a $.Each (jquery) function.
It only works when I use alert() in my code!

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    function noti(txt) {

        if (!("Notification" in window)) {
            alert("This browser does not support desktop notification");
        }

        else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
            var notification = new Notification('A notification', { body: txt, icon: 'logo.png' });
        } else {
            Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {

                if (!('permission' in Notification)) {
                    Notification.permission = permission;
                }
                if (permission === "granted") {
                    var notification = new Notification('A notification', { body: txt, icon: 'logo.png' });
                }
            });
        }
    }

};

setInterval(function () {
    $.getJSON('results.json', function (jd) {
        $.each(jd, function (i, item) {
            noti(jd[i].message);
            //alert(); if i un comment this,  will work!

        });
    });

}, 5000);
});
```

The notification doesn't show!

Comment: How many messages are stored in `results.json`? Perhaps you're trying to show too many too quickly?

Comment: no i test it with only 3 record